# Primefaces datatable reset pagination

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I am using the dataTable component with the paginator in a search utility which works great but having a problem to reset paginator page to the first page.
for example you are on page 6 of the paginator and you perform a new search, the dataTable gets reloaded with the new data but, the page number is not reset to 1 it remains on 6.

I'm using PF 3.4.2.
any idea?

Comment: show the code your *search* and try adding `update="myTableId"` to your search component

Comment: My datatable is inside a panel "displayResult",so in the command button i did: `<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search"
      value="Find"
      actionListener="#{searchBean.searchCertif}" update="displayResult"/>`

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I found the solution, should add this to the CommandButton:

`onclick="wdg_dataTable.getPaginator().setPage(0);`

Comment: Please post this as an answer (you can answer your own question), and set it as accepted. Or delete this question altogether.

Comment: I've tried but I'm not able to answer my own question!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add the following javascript to the action which updates the DataTable's model:

```
onclick="myWidgetVar.getPaginator().setPage(0);"
```

Where *myWidgerVar* is the WidgetVar for the DataTable.

Ensure that the DataTable has a WidgetVar set. For further context, see [this post by Optimus Prime.](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=16644)

The above causes the grid to make a call to refresh data with existing filters. If you explicitly want the grid to load new data from page one, you can reset the datatable on server side

```
DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("dialogSelectionForm:carSelectDialogTable");
dataTable.reset();
```

Reference - http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5807

Comment: It wasn't clear that the widgetWar rather than the ID was needed.

Comment: That does the trick. However, it makes a call to the server again to refresh. What if I don't want server refresh as there is already a call doing that explicitly?

Answer (score 10):

I solved with widgetVarDataTable.clearFilters(); in primefaces 3.5, 
and  PF('widgetVarDataTable').clearFilters(); in primefaces 5.0

Answer (score 6):

I solved my problem using PF('dataTableWidgetVar').paginator.setPage(0); in Primefaces 6.0

Comment: Putting PF('') around the widget var name worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I had to solve this need in the back-end. To solve the problem without executing some sort of "duplicated refresh" I did implement this:

```
<p:commandButton ... update="dataTable" actionListener="#{myController.bindingDataTable.setFirst(0)}" oncomplete="someClientJS();" ... />
```

This code assumes the *`dataTable`* in the front-end is binding to the back-end reference variable *`myController.bindingDataTable`*. The *`ActionListener`* executes before the *`dataTable`* gets refreshed, so for that moment the paging is set with '0' as value for the first row/record (hence, first page as well).

Comment: BTW, I'm using PrimeFaces 5.2.

Comment: Also possible with DataList. And no unnecessary call to the server. Thank-you!